# Using the output of numpy.histogram how to plot a simple curve plot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot a graph b/w `a` on x-axis and probability on y-axis.

First I calculate probability using numpy.histogram command. `n` gives me probability.

But the number of terms in `n` depends on how many bins I choose.

If I choose 5 bins then there will be 5 terms when I print `n`.

Using these probability value I can pick y-axis values.

But my goal is to plot a graph between `a` vs probability, whereas in array `a` there are 9 terms and in `n` there are 5 terms.

So how I will convert probabilities of histogram into simple curve plot?

```
a=np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,5])
n,bins = np.histogram(a,bins=5,density=True)
print(n)
plt.plot(?,n)
plt.xlabel("a")
plt.ylabel("probability")
```

Comment: I still don't get the question but @Luis has an answer below making use of bins and n. Question remains what do you want to plot using a and probability/bins?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this should work

```
plt.plot(bins, np.append(n[0], n))
```